# Hadith There is no good in christians, or christianity By RasuAllah?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation

Is this hadith found in Sunan Al-Kubra, Al-Bayhaqiy, Al-Mu’ajam Al-Kabiir of At-Tabaraniy Tabarani and Al Hakim about Muhammad (s) advising Salman Farsiy authentic?

**عَنْ سَلْمَانَ الْفَارِسِيِّ ، قَالَ : ” أَتَيْتُ رَسُولَ اللَّهِ صَلَّى اللَّهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ بِجَفْنَةٍ مِنْ خُبْزٍ وَلَحْمٍ ، فَقَالَ : مَا هَذَا يَا سَلْمَانُ ؟ قُلْتُ : صَدَقَةٌ ، فَلَمْ يَأْكُلْ ، وَقَالَ لأَصْحَابِهِ : كُلُوا ، ثُمَّ أَتَيْتُهُ بِجَفْنَةٍ مِنْ خُبْزٍ وَلَحْمٍ ، فَقَالَ : مَا هَذَا يَا سَلْمَانُ ؟ قُلْتُ : هَدِيَّةٌ ، فَأَكَلَ ، وَقَالَ : إِنَّا نَأْكُلُ الْهَدِيَّةَ ، وَلا نَأْكُلُ الصَّدَقَةَ ، قَالَ : قُلْتُ : يَا رَسُولَ اللَّهِ ، مَا تَقُولُ فِي النَّصَارَى ؟ قَالَ : يَا سَلْمَانُ لا خَيْرَ فِي النَّصَارَى وَلا فِيمَنْ يُحِبُّهُمْ ، ثَلاثَ مَرَّاتٍ ، إِلا مَنْ كَانَ عَلَى مِثْلِ دِينِ صَاحِبِكَ ، قَالَ : فَعَلِمْتُ أَنَّ صَاحِبِي كَانَ عَلَى دِينِ عِيسَى يَعْنِي الرَّاهِبَ الَّذِي كَانَ مَعَهُ سَلْمَانُ
السنن الكبرى للبيهقي

Translation of meaning: Reported on the authority of Salman Al-Farsiy, he said: I came to RasulAllah ﷺ with a bowl of bread and meat. He [ﷺ] said, “What is this, o Salman?” I said: Charity [Sadaqah]. So he [ﷺ] did not eat it, and said to his companions, “Eat”. Then I came to him [ﷺ] with a bowl of bread and meat; and he [ﷺ] said, “What is this, o Salman?” I said, “Gift”, and he [ﷺ] ate and said, “We eat gifts [gifted food] and we do not eat charity [food given in charity].”[1] He [Salman] said: I said, “O RasulAllah [ﷺ], what do you say about the christians?”. He [RasulAllah ﷺ] said, “O Salman, there is no good in the christians nor in those who love them (are fond of them / bear affinities to them) [RasulAllah ﷺ said it thrice] except the one[s] upon the like of your companion’s religion.” He [Salman] said: And I knew that my companion was upon the [true] religion of ‘Eisa [‘alaihis salam]; meaning the priest who accompanied Salman.

Sunan Al-Kubra, Al-Bayhaqiy **

and...

عن سلمان رضي الله عنه في إسلامه قال : لما قدم النبي صلى الله عليه و سلم المدينة صنعت طعاما فجئت به النبي صلى الله عليه و سلم فقال : ( ماهذا يا سلمان ؟ ) قلت : صدقة فقال لأصحابه : ( كلوا ) ولم يأكل ثم إني رجعت حتى جمعت طعاما فأتيته به فقال : ( ما هذا يا سلمان ؟ ) قلت : هدية فضرب بيده فأكل وقال لأصحابه : ( كلوا ) قلت : يا رسول الله إخبرني عن النصارى ؟ قال : ( لاخير فيهم ولا فيمن أحبهم ) فقمت وأنا مثقل فأنزل الله عزوجل { لتجدن أشد الناس عداوة للذين آمنوا اليهود والذين أشركوا } حتى بلغ { تفيض من الدمع } فأرسل إلي رسول الله صلى الله عليه و سلم فقال لي : ( يا سلمان إن أصحابك هؤلاء الذين ذكر الله )

المعجم الكبير للطبراني

Translation of meaning: It is reported on the authority of Salman [al-Farsiy] radzi Allahu ‘anhu regarding his Islam, he said: When the Prophet ﷺ came to Madinah, I made food and went [to him] with it. The Prophet ﷺ said, “What is this, o Salman?”. I said, “Charity [Sadaqah]”. Then he [ﷺ] said to his companions, “Eat” and he [ﷺ] did not eat. Then I went back until I [again] made food and went to him [ﷺ] with it and he [ﷺ] said, “What is this, o Salman?”. I said “Gift”, and he [ﷺ] broke it with his hand and ate and said to his companions, “Eat”. I [Salman] said: O RasulAllah, inform me about the christians?. He said, “There is neither any good in them nor in those who love them.” Then I [Salman] got up anxious, and Allah ‘Azza wa Jall sent the verse {Indeed, you shall find the jews and the idolators as the staunchest in enmity to the believers [i.e., Muslims]} until {spilling over with tears [5:82-83]} So I [Salman] headed to RasulAllah ﷺ and he said to me, “O Salman, Indeed your companions are the ones Allah has mentioned [in the verse].”

Al-Mu’ajam Al-Kabiir of At-Tabaraniy